# find & replace part of file path for 'src' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I have a theme switcher, and there're multiple images/icons

```
<img src="images/icons/icon-1.png">
<img src="images/icons/icon-2.png">
<img src="images/icons/icon-3.png">
<img src="images/icons/icon-4.png">
```

And also I have another set of these icons with a different color/path

```
<img src="images/icons/blue/icon-1.png">
<img src="images/icons/blue/icon-2.png">
<img src="images/icons/blue/icon-3.png">
<img src="images/icons/blue/icon-4.png">
```

the below jQuery code working perfectly when I click to change theme color for 'once'

```
$('img').attr('src', $('img').attr('src').replace('images/icons', 'images/icons/blue'));
```

If I clicked again to choose another color say 'red', the path become like this

```
<img src="images/icons/red/blue/icon-1.png">
```

while it's supposed to be like this

```
<img src="images/icons/red/icon-1.png">
```

how I can make 'replace method' to find & overwrite old path WITHOUT change file name 'icon-1.png' for example, as it's a dynamic icons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the name always the same? in that case you can use the following code

```
$('img').attr('src', function(i, src){
    return 'images/icons/blue/' + src.split("/").pop()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop and replace the `src` of each element.

```
$('img').attr('src', function(i, src){
    return src.replace('images/icons', 'images/icons/blue')
});
```

When you use the getter version of `.attr()` it will return the attribute value of the first element in the matched element set, so the same value will get set for all elements.

Answer (score 2):

Just get the filename from the source first, then rewrite the whole source. Assuming that you send as "theme" to changeTheme function, something from the following values: "images/icons", "images/icons/blue", "images/icons/red", etc. this will do the trick.

```
function changeTheme(theme) {
 var img=$(img);
 var filename=img.attr('src').split('/');
 filename=filename[filename.length-1];
 img.attr('src',theme+"/"+filename);
}
```

Or if you don't minde storing the file name as a data attribute to the image, you can change the second and third lines of the functions, with something along the lines of:

```
var filename=img.data("filename"); //assuming you are storing the file name in data-filename attribute
```